Why "Could not locate method: NeptuneGraphTraversal.property()" after addE()?
I'm trying to convert the code from this QA about copying a node from groovy gremlin to nodejs gremlin. One section of that code I've converted like so
this.__.select('source').inE().as('e').
  select('clone').
    addE(this.__.select('e').label()).as('eclone').
      from_(this.__.select('e').outV()).
  select('e').properties().as('p').                        // copy in-edge properties
  select('eclone').
    property(this.__.select('p').key(), this.__.select('p').value())

The intention is that the properties of the edge e are copied into the properties of the edge eclone.
There is of course a lot of labeling things going on between the addE and the property, but if I understand how select works, then this code is essentially like saying select('clone').addE("someLabel").from_("someNode").property("someKey","someValue"). Why then would this code result in Could not locate method: NeptuneGraphTraversal.property()?
